# What is the DOCKER_CERT_PATH in Docker for Windows on Windows 10?

Tags: windows, docker

When I was using Docker Toolbox, I could just run `docker-machine env` to print all of the current environment variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But in case of docker for windows, there is no docker machine

Still, [with `docker-machine`](https://docs.docker.com/machine/get-started/), you can create a machine with the hyperv driver. (see [`docker-machine` drivers](https://docs.docker.com/machine/drivers/virtualbox/))
See "[Microsoft Hyper-V](https://docs.docker.com/machine/drivers/hyper-v/)"

There are issues in progress though, like [issue 779](https://github.com/docker/machine/issues/779)

> `DOCKER_CERT_PATH` should be `C:\Users\<login>\machine\machines\<machinename>`

Comment: But is there any way I can find out the DOCKER_CERT_PATH if I am not using docker-machine?

Comment: Not sure: you can add docker-machine easily enough and it should list the default hypervisor docker machine that docker for Windows created for you.

Answer (score 2):

With Docker for Windows, it assumes a cert path of

```
%USERPROFILE%\.docker\machine\certs
```

Unless you specify the environment variable

```
DOCKER_CERT_PATH
```

If you're switching from Docker Toolbox to Docker for Windows, you might need to *remove* this environment variable to get things working.

Answer (score 2):

In Windows 10, you can use the command `docker-machine env`.

Docker deployment in Windows:
The Docker running on Windows 10 will be launched as a virtual machine.
So, when you set IDE env, please see below.

API_URL:

```
Docker for macOS or Linux:  unix:///var/run/docker.sock
Docker Toolbox for Windows or macOS:  https://192.168.99.100:2376
```

Docker certificates folder, in Windows:

```
$ docker-machine env
export DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY="1"
export DOCKER_HOST="tcp://192.168.99.100:2376"
export DOCKER_CERT_PATH="C:\Users\your_id\.docker\machine\machines\default"
export DOCKER_MACHINE_NAME="default"
export COMPOSE_CONVERT_WINDOWS_PATHS="true"
# Run this command to configure your shell:
# eval $("C:\Program Files\Docker Toolbox\docker-machine.exe" env)
```

Comment: I did not find `machine` in `.docker`. How can I get that?